# Redirect user after sign in in supabase and next js 13

Tags: authentication, next.js, supabase, next.js13

I'm migrating to next js 13 and I'm wondering how can I perform a redirect after the user signs in with email and password. Currently, the session and user are returning well, but if I `router.push('/')`, the session is returning null there. Currently, only the `/login` page is under the `appDir` and it goes like this:

```
  const handleSignIn = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setStatus("loading");

    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
      email: form.email,
      password: form.password,
    });

    if (error) {
      toast.error(error.message, {
        className: "!bg-red-500 !text-white !border-red-500",
      });
      setStatus("not submitted");
      console.error(error)
      return;
    }

    toast.success(
      locale === "en"
        ? "Wait! We are redirecting you"
        : "¡Espera! Te estamos redirigiendo",
      {
        className:
          "!bg-electric-violet-500 !text-white !border-electric-violet-500",
      }
    );
    router.push("/");

    setStatus("submitted");
  };
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any luck? It seems to have something to do with middleware caching

Comment: You can find some helpful resources in this discussion: https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/13879#discussioncomment-5799497

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to simply `router.refresh()` so that the session is not null:

```js
const handleSignIn = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
      email,
      password,
    });
    console.log(data);
    router.refresh();
  };
```

and when there is a session, redirect the user to main:

```js
export default async function Login({
  params: { lang },
}: {
  params: { lang: string };
}) {
  const supabase = createServerComponentClient<Database>({ cookies });
  const {
    data: { session },
  } = await supabase.auth.getSession(); // get session info

  if (session) return redirect(`/${lang}`); // redirect if there is a session
  const dict = await getDictionary(lang);

  return (
    <div className="w-[71.75rem] flex justify-center">
      <AuthForm dict={dict.auth} lang={lang} />
    </div>
  );
}
```